# Team Build's build number and $(Rev:.r)

Tags: build-process, tfsbuild

TFS Build 2010 uses an internal build number. It's similar to `$(Rev:.r)`. `$(Rev:.r)` increases in each day while internal build number are increased in other way.

The questions are:

1. What is the official name of the `internal build number`?
2. How to access `internal build number` in macro format in order to use it in "Build Number Format" within the build definition?
3. The internal number is only shown when a build fails and is only accessible via `BuildDetail` variable in team build process templates. It is not shown and could not be searched in Build Explorer. How can I get it shown and search-able in Build Explorer?
4. How this `internal build number` increases? With each build among all definitions? In a total project collection?

Comment: 1. 'Internal Build Number' is actually defined as IBuildDetail.BuildNumber, and this number is unique over all builds (thus, not the same as '$(Rev:.r)' which is unique within the 'BuildDefinitionName' within which it's used.

Comment: 4. This is unique within the 'BuildDefinitionName' format string, that is, if you coded the build definition name as "test_$(Rev:.r)" and queued 3 builds a day you would have "test_9" on day 3. Whereas if you define the format as "test_$(DayOfMonth)_$(Rev:.r)" then you would never see a rev of '9', you would see revs 1-3 for each day you built.

Answer (score 11):

Try `$(BuildID)` from MSDN's ["Work with Build Numbers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719.aspx).